# UIImageView autoresizingmask, UIImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I was watching some WWDC videos and they talk about using UIImageView to stretch your images to not incur any extra memory.  Their example was using a little text bubble, like the one you get when you long press on the tableViewCell in the Music app.  They then talk about how you would have to split it into 3 slices, the left, right, and center since the center portion has the little triangle at the bottom that points to the tableViewCell you were long pressing.  Can some explain how someone does this since they don't provide any code in their example?  Pseudo code is fine.  Looking at the documentation, my guess is:

create three UIImages of the smallest size from your graphics editor:

```
UIImage *leftImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"left.png"];
UIImage *rightImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"];
UIImage *centerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"center.png"];

leftImage = [leftImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
rightImage = [rightImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
centerImage = [centerImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];

UIImageView *leftImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:leftImage];
leftImgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

UIImageView *rightImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:rightImage];
leftImgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

UIImageView *centerImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:centerImage];
leftImgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

// do I just add them all to the subview of self.view?  Do I need to set their frames somewhere?  If so, how do I know where they go since it's 3 slices making up an image.
// release memory
```

My related question to this topic is if how would you do this in IB.  Like do you make the 3 imageViews take up the whole screen since that's what you want the image to expand to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to create three images. The point of a stretchable UIImage is it stretches the middle but not the user definable ends. You define horizontal and vertical areas in pixels that you don't want to be stretched.

It is really simple to use, here is an example:

```
UIImage *stretchyImage = [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12.0 topCapHeight:0.0]
```

Then just set it to the size you want. Nice documentation with illustrations are [here](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/08/stretchable-images-and-buttons/).

EDIT:
I think you have to create stretchable image programmatically, see [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEIQFjAC&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713997/setting-uibutton-stretched-background-images-in-interface-builder-xcode-4&ei=5JInT9qeGYaUiAKH9ZmtAQ&usg=AFQjCNF24DDKlEHW_tTD_t14SQ064RbNpw&sig2=O4KBf8_l9wOwR5u5nR-6xQ).